# I need a regular expression to check the current index of array is not present in a specific range of numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I know that there is **a lot** of information on here about regex's, but I really cant seem to get this to work. I have a for loop, looping through an array. I want to see if the current index of the array is not equal to a group of numbers (32-64). I have declared a variable `let patt` which holds the regex that I think should work, but I cant figure out the syntax to check against it. I was sure it would be `.match`, but again, not sure how to word *!.match*

any advise, solutions or even a point in the direction of a good JS regex tutorial would be much appreciated!

```
class ShiftCipher{
    constructor(shift){
      this.shift = shift;
    }
    encrypt(string){
      let up = string.toUpperCase();   //convert string to uppercase
      let uni = [];
      let newArr = [];
      let i, j;
      let patt = /[32-64]/g;            //think this is wrong...

      for(i = 0; i < up.length; i++){
        uni.push(up.charCodeAt(i))      //push converted chars as unicodes to new array
        if(uni[i] != 32){              // if unicode is 32 (space) leave as is.  //I want a regex here for != unicode 32 - 64
          uni[i] += this.shift;        // shift unicode by parent class specification (shift)
      }
    }
      for(j = 0; j < up.length; j++){
        if(uni[j] > 90){            // if unicode is higher than 90(z)..
          uni[j] -= 26;             // loop back round starting at (a).
      }
      let text = String.fromCharCode(uni[j]); //convert from unicode to string
      newArr.push(text);                       //push string to array
    }
    
    let final = newArr.join('');      //join array elements(as a string) and store in final
    console.log(final);               
  }
}
  
  const cipher = new ShiftCipher(2);
  cipher.encrypt('I love to code z!');
```

Comment: The regex `/[32-64]/` is checking whether the string contains a single character that is 3, between 2 and 6, or 4, so yep, not working as one might expect it to. If I may ask, would a solution that does not involve regular expressions suffice, or is it a strict requirement that you need to use a regex?

Comment: it would suffice, but I really want to start understanding and using regex as my code is already far too long. but any solution is a good start!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to see if the current index of the array is not equal to a group of numbers (32-64)

Char codes *are* numbers. Try numerical comparisons.

```
for (i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
  if (up.charCodeAt(i) >= 32 && up.charCodeAt(i) <= 64) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

But *technically*, you can use regex too. Creating a character range from char codes works like this:

```
var patt = /[\x20-\x40]/;   // hex 20 = decimal 32, hex 40 == decimal 64

for (i = 0; i < up.length; i++) {
  if (patt.test(up.charAt(i)) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Note that this uses `.charAt()`.

The `/[\x20-\x40]/` is interpreted as if you had written the actual characters, so in this case it's equivalent to `/[ -@]/`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to have worked I'm afraid. result: ```I"LOVE"TO"CODE"Z#```

Comment: @R.Lawrence I haven't debugged your function. I've shown you where you went wrong with your basic assumption. You need to debug your function yourself, I'm afraid. :)

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll delve a little deeper. Your regex solution is very helpful too.

Comment: @Ravikumar I guess that comment was for me. Why don't you think that `/[\x20-\x40]/` will work?

Comment: @R.Lawrence Don't try to solve everything at once. I suggest you start with exactly one `for` loop that prints for each character of the input string the character itself, its char code, your modified char code, and the resulting character. Then you add an `if` that excludes certain char codes from modification. Then you add the "loop around" for higher char codes. And once you can see it's all working, you deal with creating the output string and returning it.

Comment: ```/[\x20-\x40]/``` Works perfectly. exactly what I was after. good advice too. legend.

Comment: @R.Lawrence Glad to hear you got it working! I bet it was more satisfying to figure out the remaining bits by yourself, too.

Answer (score 2):

As your wraparound constant is 26, the length of the English alphabet, one could assume that you want to alter only the letters, and then the magical regexp is `[A-Z]`:

```js
class ShiftCipher {
  constructor(shift) {
    this.shift = shift;
  }
  encrypt(string) {
    return string.toUpperCase().replaceAll(/[A-Z]/g, char => {
      let code = char.charCodeAt(0) + this.shift;
      if(code>90)
        code-=26;
      return String.fromCharCode(code);
    });
  }
}

const cipher = new ShiftCipher(2);
console.log(cipher.encrypt('I love to code z!'));
```